# Which part is this grey circular piece?

Tags: part-identification, piece-information

[image]

Hello all, the base of the gun barrel, does anyone know which part is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called [Middle Ring](https://brickset.com/parts/design-32187), or with the Bricklink terminology "Light Bluish Gray Technic Driving Ring Extension":

[image]

You can buy it [here on Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32187&name=Technic%20Driving%20Ring%20Extension&category=%5BTechnic%5D#T=S&C=86&O=%7B%22color%22:86,%22iconly%22:0%7D).